# Duplicate a column in data frame and rename it to another column name

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like sample below. I would like to duplicat a column in the data frame and rename to another column name.

```
Name    Age    Rate
Aira     23     90
Ben      32     98
Cat      27     95
```

Desire output is :

```
Name    Age     Rate     Rate2
Aira    23      90       90
Ben     32      98       98
Cat     27      95       95
```

How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: `df$Rate2 <- df$Rate` ?

Comment: @thelatemail, thanks alot as usual. You have been very helpful. I am very new to R. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

<sub>Answered with help of user @thelatemail.</sub>

```
df = read.table(sep="",
                header=T, 
                text="Name    Age    Rate
                      Aira     23     90
                      Ben      32     98
                      Cat      27     95")

df$Rate2 = df$Rate #create column 'Rate2' and make it equal to 'Rate' (duplicate).
```

Another option to duplicate, triplicate or 'n plicate':

```
#use ?replicate function, which replicates elements over vectors and lists. 
n = 3 #replicate 3 new columns
df3 = cbind(df, replicate(n,df$Rate)) #replicate from column "Rate" in the df object
df3 #plot df3 output

   Name Age Rate 1  2  3
1  Aira 23  90   90 90 90
2  Ben  32  98   98 98 98
3  Cat  27  95   95 95 95
```

Comment: It should be df$Rate2 <- df$Rate instead of df$Rate2 = df$Rate

Comment: @Luis `<-` and `=` are the same. The first one is just more R-like.

Answer (score 9):

Replication (making a copy) of a column via `dplyr` is achieved using `mutate`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c('Aira', 'Ben', 'Cat'),
  Age = c(23, 32, 27),
  Rate = c(90, 98, 95)
)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Rate2 = Rate)

#   Name Age Rate Rate2
# 1 Aira  23   90    90
# 2  Ben  32   98    98
# 3  Cat  27   95    95
```

Comment: How would you duplicate multiple columns at the same time (using, for example, `dplyr::contains()` for selecting the columns to duplicate)?

Comment: @teppo: You could `mutate` `across` a selection of columns, or bind columns. See [this paste](https://pastebin.com/raw/Z2zXMKKC). You could `rename` the column selection before binding, otherwise the duplicate names or appended with numbers.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @Werner! Just what I needed.