# How to replicate columns in data frame by alternating column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```r
df <- structure(list(Vertebral = c(16.43, 1.06, 0.38), BoneMarrow = c(19.69, 
1.16, 1.13)), .Names = c("Vertebral", "BoneMarrow"), row.names = c("Gnai3", 
"Cdc45", "Cav2"), class = "data.frame")

df
#>       Vertebral BoneMarrow
#> Gnai3     16.43      19.69
#> Cdc45      1.06       1.16
#> Cav2       0.38       1.13
```

What I want to do is create the data frame that looks like this:

Namely for each original column name, create two copies: with 'control' and 'treated' as suffix.

```r
      Vertebral.control  BoneMarrow.control Vertebral.Treated BoneMarrow.Treated
Gnai3     16.43          19.69             16.43               19.69
Cdc45      1.06          1.16              1.06                1.16
Cav2       0.38          1.13              0.38                1.13
```

How can I do that?

I'm stuck with this code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

subtype <- colnames(df)
expand.grid(subtype,c("Control","Treated")) %>% 
 mutate(new_col =  paste0( Var1,".",Var2 ))
#>         Var1    Var2            new_col
#> 1  Vertebral Control  Vertebral.Control
#> 2 BoneMarrow Control BoneMarrow.Control
#> 3  Vertebral Treated  Vertebral.Treated
#> 4 BoneMarrow Treated BoneMarrow.Treated
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `cbind`:

```
x1 <- setNames(df, paste0(names(df), '.', 'control'))
x2 <- setNames(df, paste0(names(df), '.', 'Treated'))
cbind(x1, x2)

#       Vertebral.control BoneMarrow.control Vertebral.Treated BoneMarrow.Treated
# Gnai3             16.43              19.69             16.43              19.69
# Cdc45              1.06               1.16              1.06               1.16
# Cav2               0.38               1.13              0.38               1.13
```

An alternative solution using `rlang::sym` and `dplyr`:

```
x <- syms(rep(names(df), 2))
names(x) <- paste0(rep(names(df), 2), rep(c('.control', '.Treated'), each = ncol(df)))
res <- df %>% mutate(!!!x)
rownames(res) <- rownames(df)
```

`!!!` takes a list of elements and splices them into to call (consider what `do.call` does), more information can be found at [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: can I please ask?. What does the function !!! do?? What is its meaning? And how do we refer to it?

Answer (score 2):

A version that should be easily extended to many more columns and groups:

```
newdf <- df[0] # creates an empty data.frame with the same row count
newdf[paste(names(df), rep(c("control","treated"),each=ncol(df)), sep=".")] <- df
newdf

#      Vertebral.control BoneMarrow.control Vertebral.treated BoneMarrow.treated
#Gnai3             16.43              19.69             16.43              19.69
#Cdc45              1.06               1.16              1.06               1.16
#Cav2               0.38               1.13              0.38               1.13
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take a simple approach like this using `cbind`

```
df2 = cbind(df, Vertebral.Treated=rep(df$Vertebral), BoneMarrow.Treated =rep(df$BoneMarrow)) 

print(df2)
     Vertebral BoneMarrow Vertebral.Treated BoneMarrow.Treated
Gnai3     16.43      19.69             16.43              19.69
Cdc45      1.06       1.16              1.06               1.16
Cav2       0.38       1.13              0.38               1.13
```

You can create any amount of columns you need. Also, refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030252/duplicate-a-column-in-data-frame-and-rename-it-to-another-column-name).