# How can I write a function to duplicate several columns adding a different suffix each time, in R?

Tags: r, function, repeat, longitudinal, data-wrangling

I have several variables that need repeating 19 times in a dataframe, but I want to add a distinguishable suffix to them each time. The suffix identifies the wave of the longitudinal data, which will later be transformed from wide to long. I know there will be a way to write a function so that I don't have to repeat the code 19 times, but I'm self-taught in R and functions are not my forte!

Some example data:

```
id <- rep(1:10)
var1_W1 <- strrep(c("A", "B", "C"), 1:10)
var2 <- strrep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 1:10)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, var1_W1, var2))
head(dat)

  id var1_W1   var2
1  1       A      X
2  2      BB     YY
3  3     CCC    ZZZ
4  4    AAAA   XXXX
5  5   BBBBB  YYYYY
6  6  CCCCCC ZZZZZZ
```

I would like to add 19 duplicates of `var2` to the dataframe with unique suffixes. The first new variable will be `var2_W1` the next `var2_W2` and so on until W19.

I have looked at [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030252/duplicate-a-column-in-data-frame-and-rename-it-to-another-column-name/22030430) but it only applies to few duplications. I've also tried a general search but no joy. I imagine most people would do these duplicates inside their transformation from wide to long, but the data are so large that it takes a long time. A function to do it this way is the best option for what I'm eventually aiming to achieve.

Comment: Try `dat[paste0("var2_W", 1:19)] <- dat$var2`

Comment: Thanks so much! Super simple, and I was thinking it would be some complex function. Perfect :)