# How can I duplicate all column in data frame

Tags: r

I want to duplicate all columns from a big dataframe excepted "names"

example

```
names affx.998991 affx.998993 affx.999927 ....
an_1_1 A/A T/T C/C A/A
an_1_2 A/A T/T C/C A/A
an_3_1  T/T C/C G/G A/A
```

and I want something like that

```
names affx.998991 affx_1.998991 affx.998993 affx_1.998993 affx.999927 affx_1.999927
an_1_1 A/A A/A T/T T/T C/C C/C A/A A/A
an_1_2 A/A A/A T/T T/T C/C C/C A/A A/A
an_3_1 T/T T/T C/C C/C G/G G/G A/A A/A
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try `fichier1[, rep(seq_along(fichier1), each = 2)]`

Comment: cbind(df,df) will double up your dataframes but the order of the columns will not be the same as requested.  This link may help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030252/duplicate-a-column-in-data-frame-and-rename-it-to-another-column-name

Comment: `df[,rep(2:ncol(df), each=2)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tasks here:

1. generate duplicate columns
2. rename the resulting data frame

You can do the following (I am using a mock data frame):

```
df <- data.frame(names = "A", a.b = 1, c.d = 2)
df <- df[ , c(1,rep(2:ncol(df), each=2))]
names(df)[-1][seq(2,ncol(df[-1]),2)] <- gsub("\\.", "\\_", names(df)[-1][seq(1,ncol(df[-1])-1,2)])
```

which gives

```
> df
  names a.b a_b c.d c_d
1     A   1   1   2   2
```

starting from

```
> df
  names a.b c.d
1     A   1   2
```

Comment: Excellent and the columns are side by side. This is exactly what I needed...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  affx.998991 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 4, 5, NA),
  affx.998993 = 1:7,
  affx.999927 = c(LETTERS[1:7])
)
```

`Stringr` solution:

```
library(stringr)
df[paste0(str_extract(names(df), "^[a-z]+(?=\\.)"), 
          ".", 1:3, ".",
          str_extract(names(df), "(?<=^[a-z]{1,10}\\.)\\d+"))] <- df[,1:3]
```

If `names`always start with string `affx.`, this can be simplified thus:

```
df[paste0("affx.", 1:3, ".", str_extract(names(df), "(?<=affx\\.)\\d+"))] <- df[,1:3]
```

`Base R`solution:

```
df[paste0("affx.", 1:3, ".", sub("^(affx\\.)(\\d+)$", "\\2", names(df)))] <- df[,1:3]
```

Result:

```
df
  affx.998991 affx.998993 affx.999927 affx.1.998991 affx.2.998993 affx.3.999927
1           1           1           A             1             1             A
2           2           2           B             2             2             B
3           3           3           C             3             3             C
4          NA           4           D            NA             4             D
5           4           5           E             4             5             E
6           5           6           F             5             6             F
7          NA           7           G            NA             7             G
```

Comment: column's name are not identified like you but NA.1.NA,  NA.2.NA.....

Comment: In your question, the names are `affx.998991 affx.998993 affx.999927`???

Comment: the name exact for example is Affx.88938392 and all begin with Affx. and after there is 8 numbers

Comment: Whatever the names, my code should work all the same. Have you tried it out?

Comment: of course. I tried it and column's names are NA.1.NA to NA.3.NA. But with your example it's working

Comment: I've updated my solution using your exact names. The solution works on these names just as well (cf. output).

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
df = data.frame(names = c("an_1_1", "an_1_2"), 
            affx.998991 = c("A/A", "A/A"), 
            affx.998993 = c("T/T", "T/T")
            )

nc = ncol(df)
vnames = c()
for (i in 2:nc) {
    df$dum = df[, i]
    names(df)[ncol(df)] = paste("affx_1.", 
                    substr(names(df)[i], 6, nchar(names(df)[i])), sep="")
    vnames = c(vnames, c(names(df)[i], names(df)[ncol(df)]))
}
df = df[, c("names", vnames)]
```